# react onChange event not firing

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a list and I am mapping it to a list of components

```
sets ? sets.map(set => <Set set={set} key={set.setId}/>) : ""
```

The component is rendering as expected but none of the events are triggering on the inputs

here is one input

```
 <input className="col s5" type="text" value={set.name} onChange={ (e) => this.updateSet(e.target.value, NAME) } placeholder="Name"></input>
```

The function I am trying to trigger on change is initially coming from a redux store

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        updateSet: (exerciseId, setId, attributeToChange, newValue) => 
        dispatch(updateSet(exerciseId, setId, attributeToChange, newValue)),
        deleteSet: (exerciseId, setId) => dispatch(deleteSet(exerciseId, setId))
    };
};


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Set);
```

I am receiving it as props and then making a local function on the component to call

```
static get propTypes() {
    return {
        set: PropTypes.object,
        updateSet: PropTypes.func,
        deleteSet: PropTypes.func
    };
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.updateSet = this.props.updateSet.bind(this);
    this.deleteSet = this.props.deleteSet.bind(this);
}

updateSet(newValue, attributeToChange){
    let exerciseId = this.props.set.exerciseId;
    let setId = this.props.set.setId;
    this.props.updateSet(exerciseId, setId, attributeToChange, newValue);
}
```

When I interact with the element there are no javascript errors and neither a breakpoint in the local function or in the store are being hit.

Comment: `this.updateSet = this.props.updateSet.bind(this);` should be `this.updateSet = this.updateSet.bind(this);`.

Comment: @DavinTryon That was it thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the class method not the one coming from props:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.updateSet = this.updateSet.bind(this);
}
```